# How to Return[A++] then Re-initialize[A] ? For If[] = False

Tags: procedural-programming

I'd like to make a program such as:

```
A=1
B=-1
RandomInteger[{0,1},200];

If[#==0,
A+=Abs[B];B,
Return[A] then Re-initialize ?]&
@/RandomInteger[{0,1},200]
```

My problem is that A keeps incrementing. And do not re-initialize when it's called.

I'd like to print B and do `A+=Abs[B]` if 0; to print A then set A=1 if 1 ...

I tried to nest this loop in a meta If[] with a glance on the previous value (%), but it didn't work.

I can't use For and While neither because I need the output to be a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 1;
b = -1;
r = RandomInteger[1, 20]
If[# == 0,
   a += Abs[b];
   b,
   c = a;
   a = 1;
   c] & /@ r
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chris Degnen ! That's exactly what I wanted. I felt like an additional variable could do the trick. Wish you the best ! Sorry, I can't Upvote.

Comment: @K-Pia ... But you can accept the answer, if it solves your problem. Just click on the grey check mark next to the answer you want to accept.